# Unity PUN 2 shooting not syncing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, photon

I wanted to add multiplayer to my game but i quickly faced many many problems, i cant find any clear solution online. i made a weapon script where the player can shoot and reload.
problems:

1. when i shoot, on 1 screen both players shoot, but at the other screen nothing happens
2. when i swap weapons, on 1 screen both players swap weapons, on the second screen nothing happens
   note: im still a complete beginner so go easy on me please :)) thanks!

weapon script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using Photon.Pun;

public class weaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public weaponSO weaponStats;
    
    public GameObject reloadingText;
    public TMP_Text ammoValue;
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float bulletForce = 2f;
    public bool isShooting;
    public float pistolDamage;
    public int currentAmmoClip = 1;
    public int maxAmmoClip;
    public int currentReserve = 1;
    public int maxReserve;
    public float reloadTime = 2f;
    public bool isReloading = false;
    public int bulletsShot;
    public float startingDamage;
    PhotonView view;

    public void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();

        if(view.IsMine)
        {
            view.RPC("Update", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
        }
        WeaponStats();
        currentAmmoClip = maxAmmoClip;
        currentReserve = maxReserve;
        bulletsShot = maxAmmoClip - currentAmmoClip;
        isShooting = false;
        weaponStats.damage = startingDamage;

    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void Update()
    {

        ammoValue.text = currentAmmoClip.ToString("0") + "/" + currentReserve.ToString("0");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {        
            if(currentReserve <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
            if (currentAmmoClip == maxAmmoClip && !isReloading)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(Reload());
                return;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && currentAmmoClip >= 1)
        {

            if(isReloading == false)
            {    
                bulletsShot += 1;
                currentAmmoClip -= 1;
                isShooting = true;
                Shoot();
                FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("shot1");
                return;
            }
        }

        if(isReloading)
           return;

        if(currentAmmoClip <= 0 && currentReserve >= 1)
        {
            
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
            return;
        }

        
    }
    IEnumerator Reload()
    {

        reloadingText.SetActive(true);
        isReloading = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
        if(currentReserve <= bulletsShot)
        {
            currentAmmoClip += currentReserve;
            currentReserve = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentReserve -= bulletsShot;
            currentAmmoClip = maxAmmoClip;
        }
        bulletsShot = 0;
        reloadingText.SetActive(false);

        isReloading = false;
    }


    void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    public void WeaponStats()
    {
        pistolDamage = weaponStats.initialDamage;
        maxAmmoClip = weaponStats.maxAmmoClip;
        maxReserve = weaponStats.maxReserve;
        reloadTime = weaponStats.reloadTime;
        bulletForce = weaponStats.bulletForce;
        startingDamage = weaponStats.initialDamage;
    }
}
```

weapon holder:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponHolder : MonoBehaviour
{   

    public int selectedWeapon = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        SelectWeapon();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(FindObjectsOfType<weaponScript>()[0].isReloading == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            switchWeapon();
        }
    }

    public void switchWeapon()
    {
        int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;
        if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
        {
            if(selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
            {
                selectedWeapon = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedWeapon++;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
        {
            if(selectedWeapon <= 0)
            {
                selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedWeapon--;
            }
        }

        if(previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon)
        {
            SelectWeapon();
        }
    }

    public void SelectWeapon()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
            if(i ==  selectedWeapon)
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

i tried adding

```
        if(view.IsMine == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("true");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("false");
        }
```

but nothing happened and i couldnt shoot anymore. thanks for reading

Comment: A) you definitely have to check for `isMine` otherwise just every player will shoot since `GetKeyDown` is globally true for each and every class in your project ... B) I don't see anything at all where you would ever sync anything via the network => how should the other devices know that something happened on the first one...?

Comment: `I wanted to add multiplayer to my game` .. in general you should plan your games including multiplayer right from the beginning .. adding multiplayer afterwards is always very tricky and requires reimplantation of a lot of things. When you shoot you do a lot of things, some need to be synchronized others don't .. currently you would e.g. also not get any sound on other clients since you don't synchronize that call ... There is probably a lot more rework to be done than can be covered in an answer here ;)

Comment: `I don't see anything at all where you would ever sync anything via the network` i tried many things but i just couldnt figure out how to sync stuff properly, do i have to have isMine in awake, in update, in start, how and when? im sorry, this is my first ever game im working on (2.5 months in) and i dont have any coding experience beside the basic things ive learned so far. is there any way i can contact you? discord maybe. thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't sync anything in your game. This means the other computer can't know what it has to do.

Whenever you want to sync something you have to call an [RPC function](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent).

Maybe watch some tutorials about how to do this properly and how to set up a simple multiplayer lobby.

EDIT:
What the other comments above mentioned with `.IsMine` is true, but you're doing it wrong. You have to call this in start or awake and whenever the view is not yours you disable the camera of the person only and disable shooting. Its important to only do this on your computer! If you are not doing everyone will shoot when you press Shoot and everyone will walk when you walk.

Comment: `What the other comments above mentioned with .IsMine is true, but you're doing it wrong. You have to call this in start or awake`  i tried doing that (see below) but for some reason when i test it out, my player cant shoot anymore
`    public void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();

        if(view.IsMine)
        {
            view.RPC("Update", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
        }
`

Comment: Don't call a RPC function when the Photon view is not yours. If the Photonview is not yours you want to disable the camera and the shooting mechanic locally. Put something like this at the start of your script `if(!view.isMine) {
        camera.enabled = false;
    }` and in Update you check if the view is yours before you shoot `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && currentAmmoClip >= 1 && view.isMine)` Another thing is you should not put an RPC above Update. Make an RPC function that triggers when you shoot your weapon. In your case this rpc gets triggered in your shoot function.

Comment: i tried this
`        Debug.Log("this works");
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && currentAmmoClip >= 1 && view.IsMine)
        {
            Debug.Log("can shoot");
            view.RPC("RPC_Shoot", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
        }
`
only the first debug log works, so there must be something wrong with IsMine, i really have no clue what im doing wrong here. this is my full script https://pastebin.com/1g5YF8L3 i really appreciate your time and effort!

(still cant shoot btw)

Comment: The first thing I would do is swapping the content of the RCP_Shoot function with the Shoot function. The other players don't have to know how many ammunition you have or if one player shoots isShooting is true for everyone. I updated your script: https://pastebin.com/KzcZYXAe I can't test it though

Comment: i tried out your script and it turns out it stops working after `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && !isReloading && currentAmmoClip >= 1 && view.IsMine)`

Comment: I actually fixed it, I didn't you know you had to add the photon view component to child objects too.